# Layering ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 3 piece of data that I need to layer onto one plot. The first time series layer is coded:

```
p<-ggplot(MI_FL_Data, aes(realdate, FLday))+geom_line()
```

The next layer adds two geom_hlines at yintercept=15000 and 17000 respectively. This layer is coded:

```
q<-ggplot(MI_FL_Data, aes( realdate, FL_Actions))+geom_point(na.rm = TRUE)
```

The final layer plots the points based on a categorical variable FL_Actions at the yintercept produced in the second code. This code is:

```
r<-ggplot(MI_FL_Data, aes(realdate, FLday))+
  geom_hline(data = MI_FL_Data %>% filter(FL_Actions == 1), aes(yintercept = 15000), linetype=5, na.rm=TRUE)+ 
  geom_hline(data = MI_FL_Data %>% filter(FL_Actions == 2), aes(yintercept = 17000), linetype=1, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Now I need to layer each of these saved vectors on top of each other in one graph. When I use the code:

```
ggplot(MI_FL_Data, aes(realdate, FLday))+
  geom_hline(data=r)+
  geom_point(data=r)
```

I get an error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class gg/ggplot. I thought by saving each layer it would be fairly simple to just add them together. Any advice? I'm a bit of a novice with ggplot but what I want to do seem fairly intuitive so I'm stumped.

I've added images of each layer just in case.

[image: First Layer][image: Second Layer][image: Third Layer]

```
# data
structure(list(Date = c("1/22/20", "1/23/20", "1/24/20", "1/25/20", 
"1/26/20", "1/27/20", "1/28/20", "1/29/20", "1/30/20", "1/31/20", 
"2/1/20", "2/2/20", "2/3/20", "2/4/20", "2/5/20", "2/6/20", "2/7/20", 
"2/8/20", "2/9/20", "2/10/20", "2/11/20", "2/12/20", "2/13/20", 
"2/14/20", "2/15/20", "2/16/20", "2/17/20", "2/18/20", "2/19/20", 
"2/20/20"), Date2 = c("1/22/20", "1/23/20", "1/24/20", "1/25/20", 
"1/26/20", "1/27/20", "1/28/20", "1/29/20", "1/30/20", "1/31/20", 
"2/1/20", "2/2/20", "2/3/20", "2/4/20", "2/5/20", "2/6/20", "2/7/20", 
"2/8/20", "2/9/20", "2/10/20", "2/11/20", "2/12/20", "2/13/20", 
"2/14/20", "2/15/20", "2/16/20", "2/17/20", "2/18/20", "2/19/20", 
"2/20/20"), Date3 = c("1/22/20", "1/23/20", "1/24/20", "1/25/20", 
"1/26/20", "1/27/20", "1/28/20", "1/29/20", "1/30/20", "1/31/20", 
"2/1/20", "2/2/20", "2/3/20", "2/4/20", "2/5/20", "2/6/20", "2/7/20", 
"2/8/20", "2/9/20", "2/10/20", "2/11/20", "2/12/20", "2/13/20", 
"2/14/20", "2/15/20", "2/16/20", "2/17/20", "2/18/20", "2/19/20", 
"2/20/20"), FLORIDA = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), FLday = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), MICHIGAN = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), MIday = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), FL_Actions = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), MI_Actions = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), realdate = structure(c(18283, 
18284, 18285, 18286, 18287, 18288, 18289, 18290, 18291, 18292, 
18293, 18294, 18295, 18296, 18297, 18298, 18299, 18300, 18301, 
18302, 18303, 18304, 18305, 18306, 18307, 18308, 18309, 18310, 
18311, 18312), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**NOTE that FL_Actions shows up as NA in this sippet of the data. This is because policy actions did not occur until March and continued through November of 2020**

This is the current ggplot created with suggested code:

```
ggplot(MI_FL_Data, aes(realdate, FLday)) + 
  geom_line()+ geom_label(data=MI_FL_Data, aes(label=FL_Actions), nudge_x = 0.50, nudge_y=.25, size=2, na.rm=TRUE)+
  geom_point(na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_point(na.rm = TRUE) + 
  geom_hline(data = MI_FL_Data %>% filter(FL_Actions == 1),aes(yintercept = 15000), linetype=5, na.rm=TRUE) +
  geom_hline(data = MI_FL_Data %>% filter(FL_Actions == 2),aes(yintercept = 17000), linetype=1, na.rm=TRUE) +
  labs(x=NULL, y="Number of Reported Daily COVID Cases", title="State of Florida",caption="1= closing actions, 2= opening actions")+theme_classic()
```

[image]

Updating with suggestion. This is the code: `ggplot(MI_FL_Data, aes(realdate, FLday)) + geom_line()+ geom_label(data=MI_FL_Data, aes(label=FL_Actions), nudge_x = 0.50, nudge_y=.25, size=2, na.rm=TRUE, y=15000)+geom_point(aes(realdate, 17000),na.rm = TRUE) + geom_point(aes(realdate, 15000), na.rm = TRUE) +  geom_hline(data = MI_FL_Data %>% filter(FL_Actions == 1),aes(yintercept = 15000), linetype=5, na.rm=TRUE) +geom_hline(data = MI_FL_Data %>% filter(FL_Actions == 2),aes(yintercept = 17000), linetype=1, na.rm=TRUE)+labs(x=NULL, y="Number of Reported Daily COVID Cases", title="State of Florida",caption="1= closing actions, 2= opening actions")+theme_classic()` and this is the resulting graph: [image: Third Iteration]

Comment: *"the labels for FL_Actions are showing up on the time series line and not on the hlines"* They're inheriting `y = FLday` from the original `ggplot()`. If you want them at some other `y` value, you need to specify it in that layer. Maybe `geom_label(..., y = 15000)` (keeping all the other stuff you have in that layer).

Comment: This is what I want, however...I can't see the information on y=15000 because something is layering over it. I've added the code and the resulting image to the original question. I personally am fine with just having one hline so long as the label is readable.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 plots, not 3 layers. Every time you use `ggplot()`, you're creating a new plot. The layers are the just geoms. You need to add only the layers together, not the full plots:

```
ggplot(MI_FL_Data, aes(realdate, FL_Actions)) +
  geom_point(na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_point(na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_hline(
    data = MI_FL_Data %>% filter(FL_Actions == 1),
    aes(yintercept = 15000), linetype=5, na.rm=TRUE
  ) +
  geom_hline(
    data = MI_FL_Data %>% filter(FL_Actions == 2),
    aes(yintercept = 17000), linetype=1, na.rm=TRUE)
  )
```

I think the above should work. If it gives you trouble, please post a reproducible example - say 10 rows of data shared with `dput`, e.g., `dput(MI_FL_Data[1:10, ])`.

Comment: I think the data filtering on the `geom_hline`s is unnecessary since they are just static horizontal lines anyway.

Comment: This is a bit closer, BUT as you can see in the graph produced, the labels for FL_Actions are showing up on the time series line and not on the hlines which is where they need to be.

Comment: Code used is: ```ggplot(MI_FL_Data, aes(realdate, FLday)) + geom_line()+ geom_label(data=MI_FL_Data, aes(label=FL_Actions), nudge_x = 0.50, nudge_y=.25, size=2, na.rm=TRUE)+geom_point(na.rm = TRUE) + geom_point(na.rm = TRUE) +  geom_hline(data = MI_FL_Data %>% filter(FL_Actions == 1),aes(yintercept = 15000), linetype=5, na.rm=TRUE) +geom_hline(data = MI_FL_Data %>% filter(FL_Actions == 2),aes(yintercept = 17000), linetype=1, na.rm=TRUE)+labs(x=NULL, y="Number of Reported Daily COVID Cases", title="State of Florida",caption="1= closing actions, 2= opening actions")+theme_classic()```

Comment: link to image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PNjBlP_FzDH776SyeiN9gjz1A7H20pkS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sample:```# A tibble: 22 x 10
   Date    Date2   Date3   FLORIDA FLday MICHIGAN MIday FL_Actions MI_Actions realdate  
   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl> <date>    
 1 3/6/20  3/6/20  3/6/20        3     0        0     0         NA         NA 2020-03-06
 2 3/7/20  3/7/20  3/7/20        7     4        0     0         NA         NA 2020-03-07
 3 3/8/20  3/8/20  3/8/20       10     3        0     0         NA         NA 2020-03-08
 4 3/9/20  3/9/20  3/9/20       13     3        0     0          1         NA 2020-03-09```

Comment: Please put the sample data (and the code, and the image) in the question, not in comments. And please use `dput()` to share it as I mention in my question - then it will be copy/pasteable. If you want to label the lines directly, I would suggest using `annotate()`

Comment: The things you requested are now in the original post. @GregorThomas

Answer (score 0):

The code used to produce the following graph is: `gplot(MI_FL_Data, aes(realdate, FLday)) + geom_line()+ geom_label(data=MI_FL_Data, aes(label=FL_Actions), na.rm=TRUE, y=15500)+ geom_point(aes(realdate, 15000), na.rm = TRUE) +  geom_hline(data = MI_FL_Data %>% filter(FL_Actions >= 1),aes(yintercept = 15000), linetype=5, na.rm=TRUE)+labs(x=NULL, y="Number of Reported Daily COVID Cases", title="State of Florida",caption="1= closing actions, 2= opening actions")+theme_classic()`

However, the size of the hline is still concerning and I'm not sure exactly how to get the bolded overlay to go away. Any suggestions on this are welcome. [image]